# Who does this sculpture depict?

Tags: identification, sculpture

I know I've seen it somewhere before. But can't for the life or me remember who this sculpture is of?  Any help would be greatly appreciated. .

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the images from? Is the sculpture in your possession? If so, where did you get it?

Comment: My wife's uncle recently passed away and we came across it whole cleaning out a shed behind the house. It says "Handarbeit Handiwork Made in Germany Copyright" on the bottom.                                           Thank you very much.